# Error con archivo en vb.net

Tags: vb.net, .net

Al Abrir Visual Studio y querer modificar en Diseño un form en el que estaba trabajando me aparece

*Captura de pantalla:*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si miro la carpeta, estan los archivos.

¿Qué debo hacer para que me vuelva a mostrar en Diseño ese Form?

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 4):

Podrias usar la opcion `Open With...` para cambiar con que editor visualizas el item, quizas por alguna razon se cambio por eso visualizas el binario en lugar de texto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]